# Rack Hardware Mounting Issue

Tags: switch, rack-layout

I have recently been hired on as an IT specialist at a company, and have been given the task of upgrading several old switches with brand new beautiful devices.  The only issue is the existing rack's depth cannot accommodate the new gear (power cable protrudes) by about two inches.  It has been suggested to me that what I require is a "standoff extender bracket".  Ref. 
 http://www.rackmountsolutions.net/standoff_rack_extender.asp 
For the life of me as I look at this device I cannot figure out how it is supposed to securely mount to the existing rack.  The screw holes must be facing outwards to accept the mounting screws for the switch, but then all that is left attach the extender to the rack are a set of notches.  In the one photo I have been able to find of one already attached it appears that I would take apart the rack, and slide this in between.  Ref. 
 http://www.rackmountsolutions.net/images/Standoff-Brackets-A.jpg 
 But that seems a bit ridiculous.  I feel like I'm missing something very simple here.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Seriously? You cannot see how those work? The reason they have an open hole is make it easier to drive the screw -- you can run the screw almost all the way down *then* place the extender. Also, many devices can have the rack ears turned around to offset them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call notches are screw holes that allow you to adjust the left-right position.

The rack and mounted equipment needs to have a minimum 1 meter clearance behind it.  You should relocate the rack itself.